# How to prevent class object inside a class to try constructing itself automatically without a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have this next class:

```
#include "OutStream.h"
#include "FileStream.h"

class Logger
{
    OutStream _os;
    FileStream _fs;
    bool _logToScreen;
    static unsigned int _line;

public:
    Logger(const char *filename, bool logToScreen);
    ~Logger();

    void print(const char *msg);
};
```

The class `OutStream` has a default constructor but the class `FileStream` doesn't have a default constructor.
When I'm trying to code the constructor for `Logger` i get an error that says "No default constructor exists for class 'FileStream'"
Here is the code of the Logger constructor, where I construct _fs also:

```
unsigned int Logger::_line = 0;
Logger::Logger(const char* filename, bool logToScreen)
{
    // Opening the given file in the FileStream class
    _fs = FileStream(filename);
    // Declaring the value of _logToScreen
    _logToScreen = logToScreen;
}
```

How can I fix this issue while keeping the `_fs` private in Logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mem-initializer-list. Define the constructor like

```
Logger::Logger(const char* filename, bool logToScreen) : _fs( filename ), _logToScreen( logToScreen )
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. What is the difference between what I did and what you suggested?

Comment: The difference isthat this approach constructs the members directly, whereas your approach default-constructs them first, and then assigns to them in the constructor body.

Comment: @0xBlackMirror Then the body of a constructor gets the control all its subobjects are already constructed.  So within the body you cam deal with assignment operators. IWhen a mem-initializer is used then the corresponding subobjects are constructed using the specified initializers.